# Prevent form submission by pressing back button laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

- Click button -> go to form
- Page 1: Form
- Page 2 : Form - > submits information from both pages
- page 3 -> completion page after form is submitted

I want to stop users from just pressing back and going to the second page. They have to go and click the button to submit **a new form** .

Answer (score 0):

You should apply this Post/Redirect/Get method to prevent user to go back to 2nd page.

There is specific page to understand the [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

There is also a way to keep the post data if you need it. You can see from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692521/how-to-keep-post-methods-input-values-with-post-redirect-get)  link.